# Formatting text in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

from the command line to redirect an ouptput to another file I am aware that I can do something like this

```
$ echo randomText > file.md
```

I am also aware that, if I want to append the output to the end of the file, I can do something like this

```
$ echo randomText >>  file.md
```

Now if I cat the content of file.md I will see something like

```
randomText
randomText
```

Is there a way to format the output that is being sent to the file. Rather than appending to the end I am hoping to achieve something like this

```
randomText -----------------------------------  randomText
```

Comment: Why not append `-------------------------------------- randomText` instead?

Comment: notice how the last one does not have ----------------- at the end. I have some complex loop going on in my shell script that needs formatting. I just simplified the question to just a general  idea of whether that was possible

Comment: `printf`, `fmt`, `pr`, `indent`, `[nt]roff`, `tbl`, and many other, along with other scripting tools (`awk`, `perl`, `sed`, even `ed`), all are capable of various types of formatting. You might need to better specify exactly what kind of thing you're trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, I used printf to format the ouput that was being sent to the file.

```
printf "%10s", "------------------------------------------" > file.md
```

To append to the same line, yuou could use printf to tab it.

Answer (score 0):

While going through loop you can try this

```
echo -ne "randomText" >> logfile
# some other actions
echo -ne "--------------------------------------" >> logfile
echo -ne "randomText" >> logfile
```

In logfile you can now find

```
randomText--------------------------------------randomText
```